# Convert SQL data aggregation code to Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I am new to Python, and need to convert a simple SAS SQL code for data aggregation to Python.

Take iris data as example:

```
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
```

What I do in SAS:

```
create table data_2 as 
select species
      ,petal_width
      ,sum(sepal_length) as total_length
      ,sum(sepal_length*sepal_width)/sum(sepal_length) as ratio
 from flowers
 group by 1,2;
```

Output

```
species    petal_width   total_sepal_length  ratio
setosa        0.1           29                 3.24
------         ---          ---                ---
```

I will need to convert hundreds of this kind of queries to Python. I used Python groupby and sum function, but I can only do it step by step, so my code is very lengthy. How can I do it in Python in an efficient way?

Comment: If you're using "groupby", it sounds like you're using pandas. If so, is the point that you have a data frame and you want to perform on it the operations equivalent to what that piece of SQL does? And if so, could you provide an example data frame as well as the desired output? (What we would refer to as a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: @fuglede  yes. I need data frame, and want to get aggregation result equivalent to what SQL does, including new column naming.

Comment: So you're asking us to write the pandas code for you?

Comment: @roganjosh  yes. it will be extremely helpful if you can write some some code for me to start with. Thank you.

Comment: But Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. We help with issues in existing code; this is too broad.

Comment: show us the python code that you used. and we can emulate on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is your data frame, then something like `df.groupby(['segment', 'time']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'total': x.weight.sum(), 'rate': (x.weight*x.score).sum()/x.weight.sum()}))` should do the job. For instance,

```py
In [111]: df
Out[111]:
  segment  time  weight  score
0       A     0      10     30
1       B     1      20     40
2       A     0      30     50
3       B     1      40     60

In [112]: df.groupby(['segment', 'time']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'total': x.weight.sum(), 'rate': (x.weight*x.score).sum()/x.weight.sum()}))
Out[112]:
              total       rate
segment time
A       0      40.0  45.000000
B       1      60.0  53.333333
```

Comment: thank you. I was working on creating a data sample for my question, and did not notice you have provided an answer.  really appreciate it.    I am new to stack overflow , will keep the forum rules in my mind for my future questions.

Comment: No worries, and welcome to Stack Overflow!